# eigen normalized() not functioning

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a class called Pulse that looks like the following plus some irrelevant functions:

```
Pulse::Pulse(const double amplitude,
         const double delay,
         const double width,
         const double freq,
         const Eigen::Vector3d &wavevector,
         const Eigen::Vector3d &field_orientation)
: amplitude(amplitude),
  delay(delay),
  width(width),
  freq(freq),
  wavevector(wavevector),
  field_orientation(field_orientation.normalized())
{
}

Eigen::Vector3d Pulse::operator()(const Eigen::Vector3d &r,
                                  const double t) const
{
  const double arg = wavevector.dot(r) - freq * (t - delay);
  return (amplitude * 2 * field_orientation * gaussian(arg / width) * cos(arg));
}
```

I call `operator()` and expect it to return what it clearly should return, however I am getting values off by a factor of 1 / norm(field_orientation).

Through my testing I have discovered that in the initialization line of the class `field_orientation` is not being properly normalized.  When I replace `field_orientation` in the return statement of the function with `field_orientation.normalized()`, I am getting the proper values.

Any ideas as to why the vector is not being normalized as is?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. I can't replicate your error. Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: I am also having trouble replicating it.  It seems to only be failing in one case and working in others.  I have two ways of running this code.  One is actually running the entire program that this belongs to and I get the normalization error.  I can also run it through a Boost test case and the normalization works fine.  I will have to play around some more before I can give you anymore information.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Turns out it is an error due to the way I construct the class.  In the test case I was using the normal constructor for a pulse, but in the whole program I use a default constructor that doesn't use the normalization in the initialization line. It is now fixed.